# Exporting to PDF changes axis scales in r

Tags: r, pdf, export

The following example looks like my data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(123)
a=sample(1:100, 100)
b=sample(1:50, 100, replace = TRUE)
obj= data.frame(a,b)

ggplot(obj, aes(a, b, col=a))+
               geom_point()+
               geom_path()+
               coord_cartesian(xlim =c(0, 100), ylim = c(0, 50))
```

The numbers are scaled here, the xaxis is twice as long as the y axis as visible in R. However, as soon as I arrange them with grid.arrange and transfer them to PDF, the plots become squared:

```
plot1=ggplot(obj, aes(a, b, col=a))+
               geom_point()+
               geom_path()+
               coord_cartesian(xlim =c(0, 100), ylim = c(0, 50))

plot2= ggplot(as.data.frame(c(1,2),c("1","2")), aes(1,1))+
               geom_point()

plot3= ggplot(obj,aes(a))+
               geom_histogram()

grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, plot1, plot3, nrow=2)
```

I made my PDF in landscape shape to fit the graphs, but they stay squared.
Adding 'width' seems just to scale the position of the 4 graphs, not the axis.
I played around with cowplot, but this one is not compatible with PDF (I am running a loop over many data files that collects the graphs in one PDF file.
Anyone has other suggestions?
Thank you in advance.

And a bonus question... How to switch the legend so that dark 25 is on top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep the same ratio between x and y length, maybe you can add the argument `aspect.ratio` into `theme` of your first plot. Here, I used `aspect.ratio = 0.5` to make x axis twice longer than y axis but you can play with this in order to get the appropriate size for your plot.

To change the legend order, you can have the use of argument `guide_colorbar` and `guide_legend` in `guides` function.

Altogether, you can do the following:

```r
plot1=ggplot(obj, aes(a, b, col=a))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_path()+
  coord_cartesian(xlim =c(0, 100), ylim = c(0, 50))+
  theme(aspect.ratio = 0.5)+
  guides(color = guide_colorbar(reverse=TRUE),
         size = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))

plot2= ggplot(as.data.frame(c(1,2),c("1","2")), aes(1,1))+
  geom_point()

plot3= ggplot(obj,aes(a))+
  geom_histogram()

grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, plot1, plot3, nrow=2)
```

[image]

Does it look what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to be able to help ;)

Comment: Now that you have this plot open anyway... Do you know how to change the label of the legend that 25 is on top??

Comment: 25 on top with lighter color or with darker color ?

Comment: Darker color (like it is now). So just a switch of the legend up side down...

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly. Briefly, you have to use `guide_colorbar` and `guide_legend`.

Comment: Amazing! You taught me a lot! (I added the question to the original question, so that people are not wondering why you changed the legend ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208508/discussion-between-rosanne-and-dc37).

Answer (score 1):

Do you only need the two figures in the left column need to have the dimensions of 1:2, and the right two need to be square? If so, you could try a combination of using both the `heights` and `widths` arguments to `arrangeGrob()` or `grid.extra()`, along with specifying the width and height of the total image in ggsave. I've found using a combination of `arrangeGrob` and `ggsave` to be the most stable at keeping the dimensions predictable.

You could try:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(123)
a=sample(1:100, 100)
b=sample(1:50, 100, replace = TRUE)
obj= data.frame(a,b)

plot1=ggplot(obj, aes(a, b, col=a))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_path()+
  coord_cartesian(xlim =c(0, 100), ylim = c(0, 50))  #+
  #theme(legend.position = "none")

plot2= ggplot(as.data.frame(c(1,2),c("1","2")), aes(1,1))+
  geom_point()

plot3= ggplot(obj,aes(a))+
  geom_histogram()

bigplot <- arrangeGrob(plot1, plot2, plot1, plot3, 
                       nrow=2, 
                       heights = c(2, 2),
                       widths = c(4, 2))

ggsave("bigplot.pdf", 
       bigplot,
       width = 11,
       height = 8.5,
       units = "in")
```

Comment: Thank you (also for your edit suggestion, I indeed forgot the librarys!). For now, the aspect.ratio did it for me, but your addition if very usefull if I want to add more graphs!